# UWP IPC: background->foreground communication

Tags: .net, windows, uwp

I have a background task in UWP that needs to send requests to a foreground app. The foreground app should be launched if it's not running, and remain running in the foreground until the background task explicitly tells it to stop.  I've tried LaunchUriForResults but this keeps the foreground app alive only for the duration of a single request.
So far I haven't found a straightforward way to do this in UWP.  Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to launch an app into the foreground UI from an app's background process, only a foreground app, a user or a [StartupTask](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/08/01/configure-app-start-log/) can perform that launching operation. You can launch your app's process into the background using an [In-Process App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/convert-app-service-in-process). That would provide a method of communication between your background task process and app process, but you would see similar time limits before the AppServiceConnection timed out.

Another method you could use is to run your background tasks within the app process using [In-Proc Background Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task). That would enable your task to communicate with your app without using an IPC mechanism.